# extract only numbers from textarea using php

Tags: php

i have a textarea each line in textarea contains numbers or names , i want to extract only number from textarea .

this my code

```
<?php 

    $allUsers = $_POST['allusers'];
    foreach(explode("\n", $allUsers) as $line) {
        
        if (is_numeric($line)) {
            echo $line."\n";
        }

    }
?>
```

and example of textarea data :

```
<textarea>
156444
978455
amoka
123
auman
</textarea>
```

Comment: Seems to work OK for that small example; https://onlinephp.io/c/9a502. Is there an issue you're running into?

Comment: @waterloomatt not work when data come from textarea  $_POST['allusers'] , It returns a blank page

Comment: Are you sure it's a `method=post` form, instead of `get`. `var_dump($_POST);` see what you receive.

Comment: `is_numeric($line)` won't be true if the line ends with whitespace. There could be spaces or `\r` at the end of the lines. Try `is_numeric(trim($line))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove whitespace around the line before checking if it's numeric.

```
    foreach(explode("\n", $allUsers) as $line) {
        $line = trim($line);
        if (is_numeric($line)) {
            echo $line."\n";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution using regex

```
 $text = 'ggd 56756 sadhgsagdahdgash  dhjghjg 324324 3  432 423 4 324hjhghjgjh 343434 34 34 hgjhghj';
    
    preg_match_all('/\d+/', $text, $matches);
    
    $numbers = $matches[0];
    
    print_r($numbers);
```